# Using Two onTextChanged Listerners(Android)

Tags: java, android, textchanged

I'm trying to create a simple currency converter and I'm modeling it after Google's currency converter, where the user would enter an amount in one field and the app would convert and display the amount in the corresponding field.

For this I've decided to use `onTextChanged` Listeners because I want it to update as the user is typing the amount it.

Here are some code snips to paint a clearer picture.

```
private EditText Dollar,Euro;
private double Result;
private String Amount,Amount2;

Dollar=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbDollar);
Euro=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbEuro);

 Dollar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                try
                {
                    Euro.setText(" ");
                    Amount=Dollar.getText().toString();
                    Result=0.92*Double.parseDouble(Amount);
                    Amount2 = String.format("%.2f", Result);
                    Euro.setText(Amount2);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Euro.setText("0.00");
                    Log.e("Error","Unable to convert a blank Number");
                }
            }
```

This code worked fine right up until i added the same code for the Euro field,after it was added the app just crashes when any figure is put it.

I do suspect that when, for example, a figure is inserted into the dollar field it calculates the euro and inserts it into the euro field which then triggers the `onTextchanged` listener for the Euro, calculates the dollar and trys to insert it there, creating an infinite loop almost and then crashing the app.

I did think that a solution would be to specify that the `onTextChanged` Listener would only trigger from user input but i haven't been able to find anything on the subject.

Included the Euro `onTextChanged` Listener for interest sake and all this code is declared in the OnCreate method if that makes any difference.

Thank you

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                try
                {
                    Amount=Euro.getText().toString();
                    Result=1.09*Double.parseDouble(Amount);
                    Amount2 = String.format("%.2f", Result);
                    Dollar.setText(Amount2);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Dollar.setText("0.00");
                    Log.e("Error","Unable to convert a blank Number");
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you post the logcat???

Comment: Design your code to something like this: First when the dollar edittext is in focus, set the listener and when it loses focus, remove the listener. Do the same for your Euro edittext.

Comment: How about listening to focus-loss or ime-options keyboard events instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the focus of the edit texts in their respective onTextChanged listener. If the edit text is not focused just return before your try catch block.

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: I would do this and also use a single `TextWatcher` for both `EditText` using the appropriate conversion factor depending on the currently focused `EditText`

Comment: I've used an If statement and the .hasFocus() method to check which edittext box is selected and it all works 100%. Thank you both :) if this wasn't what you had in-mind please feel free to let me know, I'm always up for learning different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I think when the first text changed, you should remove the other listener. Change the text and re-add the listener.

You can use :
    removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#removeTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)